# WebStorm reports "Missing import statement" when trying to use the undefined primitive

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webstorm, jsx

Starting today, WebStorm yells anytime I try to use the `undefined` primitive by saying that I am "Missing [an] import statement", and prompts me to import something as undefined. Here's an example:

[image]

My project is written in ES6+ and JSX, and the only action I performed today other that write code is run `yarn upgrade --latest` and fix any migration errors. The `redux-devtools-extension` was updated, which makes me think this is an indexing issue, but refreshing my indexes didn't change anything. I also can't find any old post with this specific issue.

Comment: `redux-devtools-extension` exports `EnhancerOptions.undefined` - thus the issue... but, when using most recent `redux-devtools-extension`, I have `undefined` resolved to definition in `node_modules/redux-devtools-extension/index.d.ts`, and no prompts to import it are shown...

Comment: Please follow this issue on WebStorm's tracker for updates: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-34013